# How can I move the "No File Chosen" to below the "Choose File" button in a form file input?

Tags: html, css, forms, file-upload

Has anyone been able to move the file text below the input button? (see image below)

[image]

I've been searching here and google, but all I can find is how to change the text wording or how to hide it, does anyone know how to move it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a custom button:

###### HTML

```
<label class="file">
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <span class="file-custom"></span>
</label>
```

###### CSS

```
.file {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.file input {
  max-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.file-custom::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -.075rem;
  right: -.075rem;
  bottom: -.075rem;
  z-index: 6;
  display: block;
  content: "Choose Files";
  height: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: .075rem solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  width: 70px;
}
```

###### Looks like this:

[image]